# Django urls.py file article detail path error

Tags: python, django

I want to be details of articles in my urls like this `help/<category>/<article.slug>` and here is urls.py code

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('help/', views.help),
    path('help/<slug:category>/<slug:slug>', views.article_detail)
]
```

Here I am connecting the urls (I think here is the problem).

```
class HelpArticle(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(HelpCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} ({self.category.title})'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def return_path(self):
        return f'{self.category.slug}/{self.slug}'
```

And this is the HelpArticle model class. Terminal traceback says

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'help/<slug:category.title>/<slug:slug>' uses parameter name 'category.title' which isn't a valid Python identifier.
```

Comment: Edit: in html I am using that return_path method of HelpArticle model

Comment: the error you've got is self-explanatory `category.title` is not a valid Python identifier because of the dot `.` which is not a valide characeter for python identifier. it should be some thing `category_title`. (`_` is valide but `-` is not)

Comment: @cizario, share also your html part.